# Can't get particles to shade smooth

Tags: modifiers, particles, shaders, eevee-render-engine, instances

I'm instancing 2 particle systems on one object. I'm also using the data transfer modifier to get custom normals on the same object. But to use that modifier I have to enable autosmooth.

That's where the problem is, if I use autosmooth it will shade flat, but I need the custom normals to get the correct lighting/shading.

My result
[image]
His Result
[image]

Here is the .blend file: [image]

*Problem occurred while following this tutorial:
[How to Create Ghibli Trees in 3D - Blender Tutorial (LightningBoyStudio)](https://youtu.be/DEgzuMmJtu8?t=611&ab_channel=LightningBoyStudio)

No one else seems to have this problem, I've tried for multiple hours now, redone the tutorial three times, googled but none have given me any answer. Only through testing did I narrow it down to what I described above. Is there a solution to this, as the person from the video and all comments clearly didn't have that problem?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your result? If I open your file the object (part of a Ghibli-style tree) looks like the one in the video ... https://youtu.be/DEgzuMmJtu8?t=652 ... I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @Blunder I added the screenshots. The problem is that his shading is smooth while mine is flat. It makes the shadows look unpleasant and blocky while his aren't.
https://youtu.be/DEgzuMmJtu8?t=997 You can see that at this part of the video